# WEB Mobile: Autoplay video with no controls

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I've created a short animation, that I would like to implement into my website.

**The animation is only a couple of seconds long and it has no sound.**

I would like to implement it, like one would implement a GIF, meaning: I want it to **autoplay, run in a constant loop and I don't want there to be any controls**.

And so I rendered a GIF and for comparison I also rendered a .mp4-video and the .mp4 is far superior:

> **mp4:** Looks exactly like I want it to look.

> **GIF:** Even after splitting the frame-rate in half, the GIF-file is still about 5x larger then the .mp4 and it looks very noticeably worse.

So, of course, I'm implementing the .mp4 and this is how I did it: `<video autoplay muted loop>` – This works perfectly fine on desktop, but it does not work perfectly fine on mobile.

On Desktop it basically behaves like a GIF, but on mobile it does not autoplay and when I click on play it opens the video in a sort of "lightbox", or player, where everything else is gone and I just see the video.

I want the video, on mobile, to also autoplay and I don't want the browser to open any sort of player, how can I do this? Or: Is this possible?

*I really don't wanna work with a GIF, if possible. The .mp4 is just much better.*

If this is not possible with CSS, maybe there is a JS-way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it on a mobile device and it auto plays fine for me. Perhaps the `playsinline` attribute could help you out.
You should use the `playsinline` attribute for mobile devices if you don't want the video to start in fullscreen while playing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-playsinline

Comment: Thank You, Very Much! `playsinline` is what I needed, but it still does not autoplay for me. – If you want, you can take a look at the actual site I'm working on: https://www.simon-reiter.com/projects/religion.html – Please note, that this is still very much work in progress. – You have to make your viewport less then, or equal to: 600px wide and then you will see a video with `autoplay`. – It autoplays on my desktop, but not on my iPhone and I did test this in multiple browsers, maybe it's a general iPhone-Thing? I don't know…

Comment: I just found out that: `HTMLMediaElement.play()` exists, maybe that could be a solution, but I still have to figure this out…

Comment: The video did not autoplay on my iPhone because: "Low Power Mode", was active. – Found that out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655077/autoplay-muted-video-ios-11-2 :)